# why are predictions of the multi label model blank?

Tags: python, nlp, logistic-regression, predict, multilabel-classification

I am trying to do multi label classification; The data set is mainly title column contains titles of the posts and tags column contains the tags. The number of tags for a post is not fixed. The dataset is like this:
[image]

and the code I wrote is:

```
X_train, y_train = train['title'].values, train['tags'].values
X_val, y_val = validation['title'].values, validation['tags'].values
##I did some preprocessing on the data(eg.lowering, removing stop words etc.) then:
tfidf=TfidfVectorizer(ngram_range=(1,2),min_df=2,max_df=.9,token_pattern='(\S+)').fit(X_train)

X_train=tfidf.transform(X_train)
X_test=tfidf.transform(X_test) 
X_val=tfidf.transform(X_val) 
from sklearn.preprocessing import MultiLabelBinarizer
mlb = MultiLabelBinarizer(classes=sorted(tags_counts.keys()))##tags_counts.keys are all the tags contained in the dataset
y_train = mlb.fit_transform(y_train)
y_val = mlb.fit_transform(y_val)
model=OneVsRestClassifier(LogisticRegression(C=10)).fit(X_train_tfidf, y_train) 
y_val_predicted_labels_tfidf = classifier_tfidf.predict(X_val[0])
```

this prediction give me an array of all zeros which means that it did not predict any tag in this record, and when I use the inverse to get the tags in letter as follows:

I got the prediction blank `[()]`. Any ideas?

Answer (score 1):

If you run `y_val_predicted_probabilities_tfidf = classifier_tfidf.predict_proba(X_val)` you'd see that for the data-points for which the predicted labels are blank have the predicted probabilities for all the labels less than the threshold (0.5 default).

If you want the classifier to predict at least one label, you can write your own code to output the label corresponding to the maximum of all the output probabilities. Id look something like this:

```
y_val_predicted_probabilities_tfidf = classifier_tfidf.predict_proba(X_val)
y_val_predicted_labels_tfidf = classifier_tfidf.predict(X_val)
for i in range(len(X_val)):
    if len(y_val_predicted_labels_tfidf[i])==0:
        max_idx= np.argmax(y_val_predicted_probabilities_tfidf[i])
        y_val_predicted_labels_tfidf[i].append(max_idx)
```

Alternatively you could also try lowering the threshold to an appropriate value:

```
y_val_predicted_labels_tfidf = np.where(y_val_predicted_probabilities_tfidf > threshold, 1, 0)
```

Comment: Thank you for your comment, but can you tell me please the threshold of what is .5? is it for OneVsRestClassifier or logistic? because I want to try to alternate the threeshold

Comment: You can simply write `output = np.where(y_val_predicted_probabilities_tfidf > threshold, 1, 0)` and set your own custom threshold to get the desired output.